# Math and iteration of XML data on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

So I set up an EC2 micro instance to play around with and I am running a php page that pulls and iterates some xml data. I don't what is happening here but "somefile_2.mov" is not getting calculated. Any ideas?

**XML**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Name] => some name
    [Prefix] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [Marker] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [MaxKeys] => 1000
    [IsTruncated] => false
    [Contents] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Key] => somefile_1.mov
                    [LastModified] => 2014-06-20T10:18:44.000Z
                    [Size] => 2207119304
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Key] => somefile_2.mov
                    [LastModified] => 2014-06-20T10:27:47.000Z
                    [Size] => 4456151156
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Key] => somefile_3.mov
                    [LastModified] => 2014-06-20T10:44:21.000Z
                    [Size] => 9218240
                )

        )

)


<?php
    foreach ($xml->Contents as $item) {
        echo $item->Key . " Bytes : " . $item->Size . " (" . $item->Size/2 . ")<br>";
    }
?>
```

**Output (EC2)**

```
somefile_1.mov Bytes: 2207119304 (1073741823.5)
somefile_2.mov Bytes: 4456151156 (1073741823.5)
somefile_3.mov Bytes: 9218240 (4609120)
```

**Output (Local)**

```
somefile_1.mov Bytes: 2207119304 (1073741823.5)
somefile_2.mov Bytes: 4456151156 (2228075578)
somefile_3.mov Bytes: 9218240 (4609120)
```

*-UPDATE on further investigation I discovered that if I replicate the data in a standard array and not as a Simple XML object everything is ok on the micro instance.*

**Data Format**

```
<?php
$data[] = array(
'name' => 'Item 1',
'size' => 2207119304
);
$data[] = array(
'name' => 'Item 2',
'size' => 4456151156
);
$data[] = array(
'name' => 'Item 3',
'size' => 20120816
);
?>

<ul>

<?php foreach ($data as $item) { ?>

    <li><?php echo $item['name'];?> - <?php echo $item['size']/2;?> / <?php echo $item['size'];?></li>

<?php }; ?>

</ul>
```

**Output (EC2)**

```
Item 1 - 1103559652 / 2207119304
Item 2 - 2228075578 / 4456151156
Item 3 - 10060408 / 20120816
```

Comment: Hi. This question seems to be off topic because it is not related to server operation (or EC2), but more with the misbehavior of the PHP script. It would likely be more appropriate on StackOverflow.

Comment: I appreciate that. Unless it is the poor performance of hardware that creates a problem when performing calculations however unlikely as the problem does not exist locally.

Comment: Performance issues cannot possibly cause this behavior. Looks more like an overzealous PHP Cache. Your best shot will be to carefully compare the PHP configs of your machine vs. the remote instance.

Comment: ^ Good call looks like the best option is to trawl the config and see what is happening here.

Comment: A good starting point will be a side-by-side diff of the respective output of `php -i`.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an answer as a work around for me was to convert the Simple XML data object into a standard array:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
$json = json_encode($xml);
$data = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```